# Java type conversion confusion

Tags: java

In java
***byte b=1+(byte)(5.0);***  is valid
But
***byte b=1+(byte)(Math.sqrt(25));*** is invalid
What's happening here?
Both seem exactly the same as sqrt function also has double sa return type.
Does something change when function calls are involved?

Comment: `b=(byte)(1+Math.sqrt(25));` would solve this.

Comment: Yeah. But I was trying to understand why is it happening

Comment: I think it's because the literal 5.0 + 1 can not blow the byte limit, whereas the compiler does not inspect sqrt for literals to determine the outcome... i.e. an arithimetic operation has to be performed.. that's outside the realms of the compiler, which the former (literal formula) could cope with.